# R loop over raster objects objects

Tags: r, for-loop, gis, lapply, raster

I would like to modify some rasters using a loop.

```
rasters<-list(rast1,rast2,rast3,rast4)

for(i in rasters){
  i[[1]]<-i[[1]]/10000
  i[[2]]<-(i[[2]]+100)/9000
}
```

Band 1 of the stack needs to have its values divided by 10000, band 2 needs to be (+100)/9000. Currently, `i` becomes a large raster object.

Here is an example raster stack to test with

```
library(raster)

rast1<-stack(raster(matrix(runif(100),
                           ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)),
             raster(matrix(runif(100),
                           ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Not sure (and I'm not a raster-pro.). Why don't you offer code(starting with `library` calls to load any needed non-base packages) that builds a set of small rasters and then testing and demonstrations could be done. My guess is that using `[[` with a raster will not succeed. SO is all about code.

Comment: I didn’t get how you want to modify the values of your raster but that’s not how you access to the values. You need to use the embedded functions. getValues(raster) to access your values and values(raster) <- getValues(raster) * 1000 to edit your values

Comment: Also if you want to edit a list you’ll likely to be more comfortable with a lapply. If you explain a bit better what kind of edits you want to achieve on your data we can come up with a working example. You want to just edit all your values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will properly address all of your goals, but I see a basic flaw in what you are doing now. When you build a for() loop in R you probably need to iterate over an indexing value rather than indexing over an object component. When you make an assignment to i[[1]] it's (a) not changing the value of anything inside the rasters object and (b) it's changing the value and class of the iterator, `i`.

So *maybe* this would be closer to what you were attempting (although you really did not describe a well-defined process):

```
rasters<-list(rast1,rast1)
for(i in seq_along(rasters) ) {
    rasters[[i]][1]<-rasters[[i]][1]/10000
    rasters[[i]][2]<-(rasters[[i]][2]+100)/9000
}
```

This results in a value for `rasters` that has the same size and shape of the original `rasters`-object, i.e a list of two raster stacks.

Comment: Hi, I was hoping to modify the individual bands of the raster stack. Band 1 ranges from 0-10000, so to change the range from 0-1 I divide by 10000. My notation works outside a for loop, but not inside if using an iterator ```i```. Unfortunately your notation didn't work but thanks for the feedback.